# How to use customTabItem in TabControls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I am using `TabControl` with `ItemSource` as List. Based on the List, TabItems are getting generated.

```
 <TabControl  Width="Auto"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabItems, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" >
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10pt"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
```

I have created my own class `MyTabItem` inheriting from `TabItem`. I would like to use `MyTabItem` in this `TabControl`.

Can someone suggest a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTemplate

```
 <TabControl x:Name="tabCases" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Controls:ClosableTabItem.TabClose="TabClosed">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Controls:MyTabItem >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
            </Controls:MyTabItem >
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the type of the containers from `TabItem` to your custom type, you should create a custom `TabControl` and override its `GetContainerForItemOverride()` method:

```
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyTabItem();
    }
}
```

Of course you must also use this custom type instead of the built-in one in your XAML:

```
<local:MyTabControl Width="Auto"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabItems, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" >
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10pt"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</local:MyTabControl>
```